# how to access form data in servlet using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, servlets

I am new to angular js. please help me with the below issue
I have a form with a controller `loginController`. I have two text boxes `user.email` and `user.password`.
I want to post the data to servlet `onclick` of the `Log in` button.
I have written the following code, but when i click `Log in`, the data is not getting posted on to the server. Also there is no error message.

Below is my JSP file
    `

```
<html ng-app="practiceApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="practice.js"></script>
    <form name='login' ng-controller='loginController' ng-submit="login()">
        <div>
        {{hello}}
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required/>
            <span ng-show='login.email.$dirty && login.email.$error.required'>Required</span>
            <span ng-show='login.email.$dirty && login.email.$error.email'>Not a valid email</span>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" required/><br/>
            <span ng-show='login.password.$dirty && login.password.$error.required'>Required</span>
            <button ng-disabled="login.$invalid">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`

JavaScript File

`

```
var app = angular.module('practiceApp',[]);
app.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.login = function(){

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'/login',
            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            data:$scope.user
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.status=data;
        });
    }

});
```

`
I have tried all the solutions that are available but couldn't find any result.. Kindly help on this

Comment: Do you see the POST request in network tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<button>` does not cause the form to submit. Change to `<input type="submit" ng-disabled="login.$invalid">Log in</button>` or remove `ng-submit` from the form and add `ng-click="login()"` to the `<button>`.

Comment: I have tried that.. but no luck. When I am trying in web browser I got the below error `cannot read the property 0 of null`

Comment: @axn7975 also your form `name` clashes with the login function name. Change your form name to "loginForm" or something different from the login function name.