# call a function inside a servlet from ng-click

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

how can i call a function inside a servlet from ng-click - angular js ?

I have a servlet to get the list of all books in database using hibernate. I want to call that function from my html page when i hit a button using ng-click

this is the html div where i want ng-click to call the function

```
<div class="col-sm-3 bg-success" ng-click = "go('/ViewAllBooks'); ">
<h2>View All Books </h2>
</div>
```

here is the function inside a servlet that i want to call \

```
    public void listEmployees( ){

            Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  
            Session session = factory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = null;

            try{
               tx = session.beginTransaction();
               List books = session.createQuery("FROM Books").list(); 
               for (Iterator iterator = 
                                 books.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                  Books b = (Books) iterator.next(); 
                  System.out.print("First Name: " + b.getName()); 
                  System.out.print(" Last Name: " + b.getAuthor()); 
                  System.out.println("Salary: " + b.getDescription()); 
               }
               tx.commit();
            }
            catch (HibernateException e) {
               if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
               e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            finally {
               session.close(); 
            }


        }
```

Comment: do you want to view all books or list employees ?

Comment: the list of books..the name of function is incorrect

Comment: ah and your controller ?

Comment: check e.g. this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108048/how-to-access-form-data-in-servlet-using-angular-js